# Add trigger before insert SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to create a trigger that prevents from 2 users with the same nickname to registered to the same app.

For example, if I have user Bob with nickName **B123** that registered to app1
I don't want that user Brian with nick **B123** will be able to register for app1.

The table that I'm using is `tblRegisteredTo` with these columns:

```
email (key), appName (key), registrationDate, nickName
```

This is what I tried to do, but it won't let me register any user no matter if he has the same nickname or not.

```
CREATE TRIGGER ifSameNick
ON [dbo].[tblRegisteredTo] 
AFTER INSERT
AS
    DECLARE @email NVARCHAR(100),
            @appName NVARCHAR(50),
            @nickName NVARCHAR(55)

    SELECT
        @email = INSERTED.email, 
        @appName = INSERTED.AppName, 
        @nickName = INSERTED.nickName
    FROM
        INSERTED

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.tblRegisteredTo B
               WHERE B.nickName = @nickName AND B.appName = @appName)
        ROLLBACK
```

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statement that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select in your `SELECT` statement? It's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Answer (score 2):

You should not do this with a trigger.  You should do this with a unique constraint:

```
alter table tblRegisteredTo
    add constraint unq_tblRegisteredTo_nickname
        unique (nickname);
```

If you are learning SQL and this is an example of a trigger, then it is a really bad example.  You should learn how to use a database correctly.

Comment: I know, but I really need to use a trigger to solve this problem. Do you know how to do this with triggers?

Comment: Why must you use a trigger? It is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: I got an assignment to solve this with triggers . I can't use any other implementation

Answer (score 1):

Gordon's answer is right, but if you MUST use a trigger, you have to account for the records that you just inserted (expecting no more than 1 row with that nickName and appName). Also, don't treat the `inserted` pseudo-table as a scalar.

```
create trigger ifSameNick
on [dbo].[tblRegisteredTo] after insert as

IF EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM dbo.tblRegisteredTo B
    INNER JOIN inserted ON B.nickName = inserted.nickName and B.appName = inserted.appName
    GROUP BY inserted.nickName, inserted.appName
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
ROLLBACK
```

In writing this, I have gotten a new-found appreciation for the existence of the `UNIQUE` constraint.

Comment: I tried this, but I always get rollback message even when I insert user that trying to register to the same app but with different nickname

Comment: I just realized that your problem is that the records are already in the table when the trigger triggers. Editing my answer now.

Comment: It is not working. I get the following error: "Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses."

Comment: More importantly, if you want to reject an insert you should use a *before insert* trigger.